# Understanding Config file for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, yaml

I don't know if this is the best place to ask this question but I wanted to know if someone could help me understand this config file for Redis inside a node. I understand some of it but wanted to get a full understanding of what the config file is doing, in particular, each of the spec sections.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation around [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is a good starting point.  The [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deployment-v1-apps) has a brief explanation of every single field, though without a whole lot of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl explain` will provide sufficient information about each **field** in the k8s object.  All of the fields are order alphabetically

for example

`kubectl explain deployment.spec`

`kubectl explain deployment.spec.strategy`

`kubectl explain deployment --recursive` will give the skeleton of the object.

`kubectl explain $resource`